# pass user_id in nested form upon registration and save both models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, nested-forms, join

I have a nested form on my Devise registration form, which populates a join table. The join table information is not saving because user_id is nil. This is due to the fact that they are not signed in yet, so I can't pass current_user. How can I pass the user_id to save the join table (Languages Users) in one form?

relevant section of new.html.erb

```
 <%= form_for(resource, as: resource, url: registration_path(resource)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :first_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true %>
  </div>
  <%= f.fields_for :languages_users do |lu| %>
   <div class="fields">
     <%= lu.collection_select(:language_id, Language.order('language ASC').all, :id, :language) %><br>
     <%= lu.hidden_field :level, value: 1 %>
     <%#= lu.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
  <% end %>
   </div>
   <div class="actions">
     <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
   </div>
  <% end %>
```

registrations_controller.rb

```
    class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters
    def new
         build_resource({})
          resource.languages_users.build(user_id: current_user)  
         respond_with self.resource
    end
  def create
    super 
  end
 private
 def configure_permitted_parameters
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u|
          u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :bio, :location, :last_name, :first_name, :nationality, :avatar, languages_users_attributes: [ :language_id, :user_id, :level]) }
  end
end
```

here are my params:

```
  {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"v/uM0+B7/XCUKmhyFGoEKqunCllXAK50uZN5f+TDpUsxlnIsgQVPbXhEb1q1P5pmG586iaULRROyarWzAzz12w==",
 "user"=>{"first_name"=>"Walsh",
 "last_name"=>"Costigan",
 "location"=>"w",
 "nationality"=>"United States",
 "bio"=>"w",
 "email"=>"walsh@seamlessdocs.com",
 "user"=>{"avatar"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fdd25023f78 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/cn/l75pvjk9707bj93z_yykb0t40000gn/T/RackMultipart20160403-6431-1hpthwr.JPG>,
 @original_filename="IMG_4574.JPG",
 @content_type="image/jpeg",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[user[avatar]]\"; filename=\"IMG_4574.JPG\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">},
 "languages_users_attributes"=>{"language_id"=>"18",
 "level"=>"1"},
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"},
 "commit"=>"Sign up"}
```

UPDATE**  This is currently where my code is. It saves the user, but not the languages_user model

user.rb
    after_create :create_languages_user

```
def create_languages_user
 @users = self.id
 @languages_user = LanguagesUser.new(@user)
end
```

registrations controller:

```
def new
 @user = User.new
 build_resource({})
 respond_with self.resource
end

def create 
 super
end

private

def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u|
      u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :bio, :location, :last_name, :first_name, :nationality, :avatar, languages_users_attributes: [ :language_id, :level]) }
end
```

Answer (score 3):

It is simple. Just pass block to `#create` method in `Users::RegistrationsController` controller

```
def create
 super do |user|
   language_user_params = params[:user][:langauges_user].permit(:language_id,:level)
   user.languages_users.create(language_id: language_user_params[:language_id], level: language_user_params[:level])
 end 
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! Is this in place of my new controller? What would that controller need? Thank you!!

Comment: I have just `@user=User.new` in my new controller. When I run the registration now, it says `undefined method `permit' for nil:NilClass`
for  `language_user_params = params[:languages_users_attributes].permit(:language_id,:level)`

Comment: how about when you put `params[:user][:languages_users_attributes]`

Comment: just made that update, and it is still throwing the same error on this same line: `     language_user_params = params[:user][:languages_users_attributes].permit(:language_id,:level)
`

Comment: can you just tell me the output of `params` ; just put `puts params` and see console.

Comment: actually, its too long for a comment - i have them listed in the question above. thanks!

Comment: if above params is correct, try  `params["user"]["languages_users_attributes"]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108201/discussion-between-paritosh-piplewar-and-gwalshington).

Comment: Okay, I have this working, and now the error is "you cannot call create unless the parent is saved." - i think this ties back to the first comment suggesting to call after_create. Any ideas here? Thanks!

Comment: it seems like `user` record failed to save,are you sure you don't have any validation error ?

Comment: Okay, so after investigating more, my user is now saving but the nested form for languages_user is not. In my console I'm getting `Unpermitted parameter: languages_user`

Comment: I'll also add that I'm back to the after_create method in the model because of the issue with not being able to save languages_user until the parent (user) is saved. I will post my updated model in the question.

Comment: your errors are beyond the scope of this question. i have updated the answer anyway

Comment: The question is how to pass user_is and save the jointable - which isn't happening right now. The solution you updated it to gives an error `You cannot call create unless the parent is saved`  Do you not think I would need to save the join table in the model, using an after_create call?

Answer (score 2):

you can access the `user_id` in an `after_create` callback:

```
after_create :example_method

def example_method
   NameOfModel.create(user_id: self.id, etc)
end
```

Comment: I have been trying to apply this, but am running into errors. Am I supposed to be removing/editing anything in my current controller, in addition to adding an after_create to my model?

Comment: What would my controller look like?

Comment: The after_create callback goes in your model.

Comment: Yes - I get that. I'm wondering about my controller. I've been looking at other questions on that, and my issue is in my controlle - do you see how I have 'resource.languages_users.build(user_id: current_user)  
         respond_with self.resource' when I take this out to use the after_create, it breaks it. I think the after_create is a great start, but I'm looking for more detailed help on what my controller would also look like. Thanks so much - and I'm upvoting for all your help!

Comment: Currently my issue seems to be that I'm passing a hash to user. I'm getting the error TypeError in Users::RegistrationsController#create
no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
Pointing to a line with '        attribute_ids = attributes_collection.map {|a| a['id'] || a[:id] }.compact'

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
after_create :create_languages_user

def create_languages_user
 @languages_user = self.languages_users.create
end
```

Comment: What would my new controller look like? When I write the above, and my new controller has: `@user = User.new` `build_resource({})` `respond_with self.resource` the nested form section is no longer on the registration form.

Comment: this method you should use in **user.rb** file.

Comment: Yes, I get that. What would my controller look like? Just `super` or `@user = User.new` or neither of those and another solution?